# Grid of heatmaps in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have this list:

```
 [<Figure size 360x360 with 1 Axes>,
 <Figure size 360x360 with 1 Axes>,
 <Figure size 360x360 with 1 Axes>,
 <Figure size 360x360 with 1 Axes>,
 <Figure size 360x360 with 1 Axes>]
```

And I whant to show evey item in a grid, like grid plot, but I cannot.
Helpe me please.

Comment: You don't plot several `figures`, you should create a grid of subplots and plot the heatmaps into each subplot.

Comment: and how can I do that, I have trie everything :(.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 20 pictures/dataset to heat map:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,5, figsize=(8,10))

for ax, corr in zip(axes.ravel(), list_of_corr):
    sns.heatmap(corr, cmap="Accent_r", 
                vmax=1,center=0, square=True, 
                linewidths=3,annot=True, cbar=False
                ax=ax);   # magic is here
    ax.set_title('Correlaciones con Movilidad\n'+titulo+' - ' + municipio, pad =10)
```

Comment: Well I will try that, in the meantime I could solve my problem exporting every heatmap, and then importing every imagen and paste them in a subplot, it worked. Thanks a lot. I will let you know if you solutions works. Again thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. i will show you my code `
        
        # Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
        r = sns.heatmap(corr1, cmap="Accent_r", vmax=1,center=0, square=True, linewidths=3,annot=True, cbar=False);
        r.set_title('Correlaciones con Movilidad\n'+titulo+' - ' + municipio, pad =10)
        figures.append(fig)`. the **figure** list save every heatmap and that is the list that I would like to show.

Comment: Try the updated code with your `sns.heatmap` command.